# View not found due to await GetAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, macos, visual-studio

```
The view 'Search' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:  
~/Views/Home/Search.aspx  
~/Views/Home/Search.ascx  
~/Views/Shared/Search.aspx  
~/Views/Shared/Search.ascx  
~/Views/Home/Search.cshtml  
~/Views/Home/Search.vbhtml  
~/Views/Shared/Search.cshtml  
~/Views/Shared/Search.vbhtml
```

I am working on a basic web application that reads data from an api. When I run the solution and try to access the view referenced by this controller from the code below, I get this error. I have narrowed it down to being the GetAsync line of code. This works on windows however does not work on my Mac.

From what I can find, the cross platform .net framework Mono, used by visual studio on OSX, does not support GetAsync. What are my options if I want to develop/test this on my Mac but also deploy on a azure server?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Search(string ticker)
{
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(demoapiurl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync(string.Format("{0}&symbol={1}&apikey={2}", apiurl, ticker, apikey));
                if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                    var accResponse = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    var quotes = GettingStarted.FromJson(accResponse);
                    GettingStarted allquotes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GettingStarted>(accResponse);

                    return View(allquotes);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception Message: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return View();
}
```

Comment: You can check mono compatibility [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/)